# Why do my view controllers open new windows when not connected to the navigation controller?

Tags: xcode

I don't understand why my view controllers don't behave like the others? They open new windows like this, how can I change?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucmND.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Select this storyboard and make the top bar to none.

[image]

[image]